# mpjboot bash: java: command not found

Tags: java, mpi, cluster-computing, mpj-express

java and mpj express are installed in /opt in compute node. `JAVA_HOME`, `MPJ_HOME` and `PATH` are set already via bashrc.

error when running `mpjboot machines`:

```
bash: java: command not found
```

java is working already in both machines

mpjboot:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage: mpjboot <machines_file>";
  exit 127
fi 

java -jar $MPJ_HOME/lib/daemonmanager.jar -boot -m "$@"
```

Comment: can you type `whereis java` if you kick start the binary for example `/usr/bin/java` manually does it work then? do you have permissions to execute java?

Comment: - what if you write echo ${JAVA_HOME} inside a script? Maybe you didn't 'export' the JAVA_HOME and PATH variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which Linux Distribution are you using? Try placing MPJ_HOME and JAVA_HOME at top of .bashrc. It fixes this problem in case of Ubuntu particularly.

Comment: Any reason for this? As I am also running into this problem while running mpj in cluster mode. Its saying MPJ_HOME isn't set, despite being already set in .bashrc.

Comment: The default Ubuntu bashrc file has `# If not running interactively, don't do anything 
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`   and mpjboot runs in non interactive mode. If you set your environment variables below this line it will not be visible to mpjboot and it will complain.